# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre arrogante y prepotente?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, chile

La rae dice:

> prepotente
> Del lat. praepŏtens, -entis. 1. adj. Más poderoso que otros, o muy poderoso. U. t. c. s. 2. adj. Que abusa de su poder o hace alarde de él. U. t. c. s.

etimologias.dechile

> PREPOTENTE
> El adjetivo prepotente se aplica sobre todo al que abusa de su poder, porque puede más que los otros y lo sabe,y en cierto modo se aprovecha de ello. Viene del latín praepotens, praepotentis (muy poderoso,
> excesivamente poderoso, que puede más), y de él se deriva praepotentia, que nos da prepotencia. Este adjetivo se forma con prefijo prae- sobre potens, potentis (potente, que puede, capaz de, poderoso), considerado en la práctica el participio de presente del verbo posse (poder, ser capaz de). El prefijo praesignifica delante, antes, por delante de o por anticipado, pero en muchos contextos, asume la acepción de
> "más que", derivada de estas (como en predilecto, "el más amado" o pretender, "dirigirse más a algo que a cualquier otra cosa").
> La forma potens, potentis emplea el sufijo de agente -nt-/-ent- sobre una raíz que es la misma que la del adjetivo potis (poderoso) y el adverbio pote (posiblemente). Palabras como potestad, poder, potencia,
> posible, apoderar, pudiente y pujante son algunos de sus derivados. Esta raíz latina se asocia a una raíz indoeuropea *poti- (poderoso, señor).

Sin embargo, usualmente se asocia a la palabra arrogante.

Rae:

> arrogante
> De arrogar y -nte; lat. arrŏgans, -antis. 1. adj. Altanero, soberbio.

etimologias.dechile:

> ARROGANTE
> Arrogare, en latín, quiere decir apropiarse y de ahí el verbo arrogar. Arrogante es alguien (el sufijo -nte indica agente como en delincuente y farsante), que toma (sin que se lo den) honores o exagera de sus
> facultades mentales.
> Es un error considerar el prefijo a- cual si esa fuese su forma integral, completa, cuando en realidad es una
> derivación o apócope de ad-, hacia, junto a. La raíz protoindoeuropea de rogare es *reg-, la misma que da origen a recto, rey, regla. Arrogante es aquel que, de manera explícita o implícita, dice apegarse a la rectitud
> o cree que esta se encuentra en él. La arrogancia también es una tendencia a buscar y conseguir algo de modo directo y contundente, En ese sentido, podemos cuestionarnos si los líderes de la humanidad son
> unos miserables arrogantes.

Sin embargo esta palabra prepotente la he escuchado con el sentido de pasar a llevar simplemente, pasar por encima más neutral. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre arrogante y prepotente? ¿El arrogante no necesariamente tiene el poder para ejercerlo sobre otros?

> El significado de “pasar por encima”
> El Diccionario de la Lengua Española dice al respecto: “atropellar por los inconvenientes que ocurren en un intento”. Atropellar es “derribar o empujar violentamente a alguien para abrirse paso”; “agraviar a alguien con violencia o abusando del poder”; “proceder sin miramiento a leyes…” Inconveniente es “daño y perjuicio que resulta de hacer algo”.

---

Por último decir que al escucharla de inmediato pienso en una persona que actúa o reacciona en forma descarada, que atropella  a otra en una situación tensa o límite en la cual sale a relucir su verdadero carácter y que está palabra necesita de otras para entender el matiz y es porque tal vez se ha alejado de su definición tradicional, es un uso regional particular, más amplio o ve tú a saber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la principal diferencia es la dinámica: una persona arrogante puede serlo pasivamente mientras que un prepotente pasa a la acción. Un arrogante de pensamiento o palabra puede generar actos de prepotencia o no. Se puede actuar con prepotencia debido a la arrogancia, pero a la inversa no tiene lógica: actuar con arrogancia debido a la prepotencia. Una cualidad deviene de otra, la prepotencia es producto de la arrogancia.

Por ejemplo:

> Su arrogancia lo lleva a la prepotencia

> La arrogancia de creerse con más experiencia que el director provoca que  responda con prepotencia

o

> Es prepotente debido a su arrogancia

Comment: Lo que me gusta de tu respuesta es que no continua sin fin. :)

Answer (score 1):

Aunque tanto **prepotente** como **arrogante** se utilizan en el lenguaje común como sinónimos de forma indistinta y estos a su vez se encuentran relacionados con el sentimiento de superioridad que da la "soberbia". Si nos acercamos al foco podemos observar sutiles diferencias, y en estos casos no hay mejor modo para comprenderlas, que acudiendo al antiguo mundo de la etimología.

De esta manera la palabra **Prepotente** provendría de latín "praepotens-entis", con el significado de muy rico y cuya raíz estaría en el verbo "praepossum-potui (prae possum)" intr. poder más, aventajar.

Por otra parte, el adverbio latino "prae" significa delante, aventajar y por tanto, el prepotente (prae-potens) utiliza esa ventaja inicial del dinero y poder para obtener autoridad y mando y poder así estar por delante o por encima de los demás.

La persona **arrogante** , del latín "arrogans-ntis", p. pres. de arrogo. Adj. arrogante, presuntuoso, tendría su base en el verbo latino expuesto,  "arrogo" arrogarse, apropiarse, añadir, atribuir,(aliquid sibi, algo a sí mismo). Arrogarse significa pues proporcionarse, atribuirse cosas de forma abusiva con desprecio o manifestando poca empatía hacia los demás.

Así pues, la pequeña gran diferencia entre ambos estaría en el modo en que cada uno va adquiriendo el poder y en el uso y abuso en la manera de ejercerlo en su intento imparable para avanzar y obtener más poder y privilegios de los que   detentan.

Por tanto, mientras el **prepotente** utiliza la ventaja del poder que le da el dinero y sus influencias para estar o posicionarse pronto por delante de los demás, la persona **arrogante** aún con poco poder, utilizan sus dotes para atribuirse facultades y méritos indebidos para acumular o añadirse más poder, e ir subiendo en el escalafón del control y el dominio sobre los demás. De esta manera el **prepotente** aún aprovechándose de esa ventaja inicial que le da el poder y el dinero puede convertirse además en "arrogante", (*prepotente arrogante*), al "arrogarse" más poder e influencia si cabe, atribuyéndose méritos indebidos que son de otros y facultades distintas que tampoco le corresponderían. Una característica común que sobresale de otras tantas, tanto de la persona prepotente como de la persona arrogante es **su gran ego**.